# How to two have a field in my pop up editor which is not my grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

In my Kendo grid popup editor  in need two have a drop down list which is mix of(concat somehow) two fields in grid,so how can I have that?in the following I want to have a drop down list which shows(model & producer) in my pop up editor,
but at the time of saving each part should be seat in its field

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
    //   debugger;

    dataSource: dataSource,
    scrollable: false,

    columns: [
              { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
              { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, },
              { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px' },
              { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px',editor: deviceTypesList  },
              { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
              { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
              { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
              { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
              { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px',hidden:true },
              { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }],

    editable: "popup",
    //edit:
    //    function () {
    //        document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;

    //    },

        edit: function(e) {
            e.container.find("label[for='device_id']").parent().hide();
            e.container.find("div[data-container-for='device_id']").hide();
        }                                                                            
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following code. I've used a text box instead of a drop-down and made a crude demo with `split` but the point is more important.

You can use the `beforeEdit` event to prepare your data for the edit popup and place it in a new field on the model, then use this new field in your template and finally use the `save` event to apply the changes made to the custom field to the original fields.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <h3>Edit Person</h3>
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input type="text" name="test" /></label>
  </p>
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" }
    }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  },
  beforeEdit: function(e) {
    e.model.test = e.model.name + ", " + e.model.age.toFixed();
  },
  save: (e) => {
    let values = e.model.test.split(", ");
    e.model.name = values[0];
    e.model.age = parseInt(values[1]);
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```